# Remove attendee from Calendar API

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I want to **Remove Attendees** from an event I created on google calendar using **google client PHP API**

Have No idea where to start google documentation is not providing any help for this matter

Comment: [Delete Event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete)

Comment: @Rasa Mohamed Not Deleting Event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I found the Solution from an expert from Github

Remove the attendee from the list of attendees and update the resource.

For instance, if your event has a single attendee, update with an empty list:

```
$event = $service->events->get('primary', $eventId);
$event->setAttendees([]);

print_r($service->events->update('primary', $eventId, $event));
```

If your event has multiple attendees, filter the list:

```
$event = $service->events->get('primary', $eventId);

$attendees = array_filter($event->getAttendees(), function ($attendee) {
   // Remove the attendee with `foo@bar.com` email.
   return $attendee->getEmail() !== 'foo@bar.com';
});
$event->setAttendees($attendees);

print_r($service->events->update('primary', $eventId, $event));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no API call to remove attendees from an event, you have to load the event, update the attendees section to what you want it to be and then call the update method.  In general, you can only create, update (send a modified event body after loading the event) or delete events.